# How to handle strings in numeric data columns in a dataset?

Tags: missing-data

In my data set there are columns like

```
Percent of Heart Attack Patients Given Aspirin At Arrival
---------------------------------------------------------
Not Available
99%
Too few cases
100%
66%
Not Available
```

What is the generic process to handle such attributes which are numeric, but contain text like these?

I'm just looking for what would be a standard acceptable approach that I can explain in my report - but if its a tool specific answer - I have rapidminer, R and IBM SPSS Modeler to work with.

Comment: You'll get much better answers to your question if you can load your dataset in R, and `dput()` a sample of the column in question.

Comment: It also depends on whether you would like to attempt to interpret the character data and translate it into a number, or just treat it as missing, in which case Zach's answer below does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ALL the text really represents missing values, then you could do something like this in R:

```
#Remove %
dat[,columnX] <- gsub('%', '', dat[,columnX])

#Coerce to numeric
dat[,columnX] <- as.numeric(dat[,columnX])
```

All non-numeric data (e.g. string values) will become NAs.